# Spring Boot RestTemplate random ResourceAccessException: Connection reset errors

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a system that implements 4 micro-services. The four services need to occasionally share information and they do it via RESTful requests using Spring's RestTemplate. Currently about 5%-10% of the requests fail with an exception like:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://otherservice.com/path": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Again, this appears random and only fails about 5%-10% of the time. I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. Currently I am trying this:

Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
}
```

Service:

```java
@Autowired
public MyService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

public Contact addContact(Contact contact) {
    HttpEntity<Contact> entity = new HttpEntity<>(contact, authenticationTokenInfo.setTokenHeaders());
    ResponseEntity<Contact> response = restTemplate.exchange(contact_base_url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Contact.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

I have tried a number of different approaches and nothing has made any difference. I tried this for example:

```java
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

I am logging all of the requests in each of my micro-services and it doesn't appear that the requests are actually hitting the other services. They just fail. According to the logs they fail in less than 50 ms so it isn't a timeout issue. For a couple of them I have implemented an exponential back-off retry but that isn't really a viable solution.

Comment: I've been seeing something similar, but it's intermittent and hard to catch. The only clue I have is that it started when I added the use of ClientHttpRequestFactory in the '@Bean' for RestTemplate. I'd be interested to know if you can test removing use of this in your '@Bean' method does the error stop occurring?

Comment: Off topic comment, but is it possible to escape @ in comments? SO thinks you're trying to @ mention someone

Comment: Honestly, I gave up trying to fix it. I am no longer injecting the rest template and am just creating a new one when I need it. I tried a hundred different things including creating a RestTemplate connection pool and nothing else worked.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue consuming Salesforce REST API. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I have not found one yet

Comment: Does anyone have any new information about this issue?  I am trying @Gremash solution of creating a new RestTemplate whenever I need it.  So far it seems to be working.

Comment: Don't know if anyone has found a solution for this I am facing the same problems as well to the Salesforce REST API as @Nix but I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846091/spring-boot-resttemplate-resourceaccessexception-i-o-error-on-post-request-fail) which seems to fix the symptoms by retrying at least I can't see that it fixes the actual problem though I am no longer getting the actual ResourceAccessException but some exception must be happening I would assume when the retry is called.

Comment: I can at least see that the cause of the retry is a `Connection reset` exception which is usually causing the ResourceAccessException for me

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with same problem. Seems like the problem is with idle connections in pool.
This resolve problem in my case and no any error occasionally occurred

```
     HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .evictIdleConnections(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
```