# Spring Boot RestTemplate ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request failed to respond

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httpclient, resttemplate

I use Spring Boot and faced the following issue while keeping the long running connection to 3rd party REST service:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:5000/products/10": localhost:5000 failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:5000 failed to respond
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:435)
    at com.example.pipeline.domain.service.nlp.NLPService.getDocumentsInfoNew(NLPService.java:42)
    at com.example.pipeline.domain.batch.steps.NLPTasklet.execute(NLPTasklet.java:170)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:394)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:5000 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpRespons
```

This service can keep the connection for one hour or more before it will return the result.

My `RestTemplate` configuration looks like:

```
public static RestTemplate createRestTemplate(int connectionTimeoutMs, int readTimeoutMs, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutMs);
        httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutMs);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
        interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory));
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
                .map(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::cast).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found"));
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance).map(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::cast).forEach(a -> {
            a.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
            a.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        });

        return restTemplate;
    }

}

RestTemplate restTemplate = HttpUtils.createRestTemplate(60 * 1000, 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000, objectMapper);
```

Is there anything I can do in order to fix it on my side or this is a pure issue on `http://localhost:5000` service side and should be fixed there?

Comment: First check http://localhost:5000 is responding in postman or similar tool. If the api is responding then you have to fix in your code else its 3rd party service problem.

Comment: My code is able to communicate with this service in 80% of time but sometimes the same code throws the exception I have mentioned in my question. So I'm just wondering is there anything I can do in order to fix it on my side or this is a pure `localhost:5000` service issue and it is impossible to fix on my side anymore?

Comment: in that case i think problem is with localhost:5000 service only.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I came to this exception too. Almost 1% of post request will occur this exception

Comment: @CharlieLin please see my answer below. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 14):

Finally, I came up with the following RestTempleat configuration:

```
public class HttpUtils {

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpUtils.class);

    private static final int HTTP_CLIENT_RETRY_COUNT = 3;

    private static final int MAXIMUM_TOTAL_CONNECTION = 10;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_CONNECTION_PER_ROUTE = 5;
    private static final int CONNECTION_VALIDATE_AFTER_INACTIVITY_MS = 10 * 1000;

    public static RestTemplate createRestTemplate(int connectionTimeoutMs, int readTimeoutMs, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

        // Set the maximum number of total open connections.
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAXIMUM_TOTAL_CONNECTION);
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections per route, which is 2 by default.
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAXIMUM_CONNECTION_PER_ROUTE);

        connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(CONNECTION_VALIDATE_AFTER_INACTIVITY_MS);

        clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager);

        clientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(HTTP_CLIENT_RETRY_COUNT, true, new ArrayList<>()) {

            @Override
            public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
                LOGGER.info("Retry request, execution count: {}, exception: {}", executionCount, exception);
                return super.retryRequest(exception, executionCount, context);
            }

        });

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(clientBuilder.build());
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutMs);
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(readTimeoutMs);
        httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutMs);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
        interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory));

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
                .map(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::cast).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found"));
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance).map(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::cast).forEach(a -> {
            a.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
            a.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        });

        return restTemplate;
    }

}

public class LoggingRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingRequestInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    traceRequest(request, body);
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    traceResponse(response);
    return response;
    }

    private void traceRequest(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.debug("===========================request begin================================================");
    LOGGER.debug("URI         : {}", request.getURI());
    LOGGER.debug("Method      : {}", request.getMethod());
    LOGGER.debug("Headers     : {}", request.getHeaders());
    LOGGER.debug("Request body: {}", new String(body, "UTF-8"));
    LOGGER.debug("==========================request end================================================");
    }

    private void traceResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody(), "UTF-8"));
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        inputStringBuilder.append(line);
        inputStringBuilder.append('\n');
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    LOGGER.debug("============================response begin==========================================");
    LOGGER.debug("Status code  : {}", response.getStatusCode());
    LOGGER.debug("Status text  : {}", response.getStatusText());
    LOGGER.debug("Headers      : {}", response.getHeaders());
    LOGGER.debug("Response body: {}", inputStringBuilder.toString());
    LOGGER.debug("=======================response end=================================================");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I recently resolved "I/O error on POST..." error in my project.**

After a lot of debugging, I could troubleshoot that this issue I received was due to CORS configuration on the target REST API project.

I could resolve it by *adding the allowed origin* in the target project.

`configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("/**");`
OR
you can add a specific source origin from which you are making the REST API call.

This solution can be considered only in case the target REST API project source is in your control.

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether the Service URI is up and running.