# HTTP client to Gunicorn/Flask application throws I/O error on POST request failed to respond

Tags: python, flask, httpclient, gunicorn

I'm trying to connect to Python Flask application deployed on Gunicorn. Gunicorn and Flask application keep the connection for the long time - for example sometimes from 15 minutes to 1 hour. Very often(but not always) my HTTP client fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:5000/products/10": localhost:5000 failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:5000 failed to respond
```

I know that keeping the long running connection is a bad solution but I can't change the Flask application right now(I'm not the Python developer and also not the author of this code). Is there anything(for example Gunicorn/Flask configurations) that I can do without application code rewrite in order to fix this?

Comment: `failed to respond` sounds like a client side timeout? If server closes connection, it should be something like `connection reset`. Could you provide more information about server side logs?

Comment: Do you mean logs from Flask application ? In case of my client configuration please see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846091/spring-boot-resttemplate-resourceaccessexception-i-o-error-on-post-request-fail I have configured pretty long timeouts 1 min for connection and 3 hours for read.

Comment: Yep, I think related logs of `flask` and `gunicorn` would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately unable to get the logs right now.. working with the system like with black box :(