# Spring RestTemplate ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request failed to respond

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am getting below while connecting with api.
This is random error. connection wait for certain time and throwing error.
Not getting error every time.

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
> POST request for **"https://test.com/api1/d3/init":** Connection
> reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:524)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:485)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:436)

I tried to understand the issue from below post but not get much idea on that.
[Spring Boot RestTemplate ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request failed to respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846091/spring-boot-resttemplate-resourceaccessexception-i-o-error-on-post-request-fail)

Please provide your valuable suggestion on this.

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Yes. Issue with the proxy that we were using to connect with the internet.

Comment: alternate option you can use is to add timeout and do retry for twice or thrice.